# Error Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null - PHP - POO -MVC-MySQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

Actualmente estoy haciendo un crud en PHP, pero me está generando este error he estado tratando de ubicarlo pero nada que puedo

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/vol8_8/epizy.com/epiz_23534135/htdocs/crud1/vistas/inicio.php on line 5
```

No se que será más util para la comunidad si dejar el enlace de Github o agregarlo en esta via, ya que como son varios archivos motivado que esta en MVC creo que podría confundir.

Este es el enlace a github: **https://github.com/felloz/crud1**

Y el codigo de los 3 archivos que considero más importantes.
1. conexion.php

```html
<?php

class Conexion {

    //Atributos
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $db;

    //Constructor    
    public function __construct(){

        $this->host="localhost";
        $this->user="root";
        $this->pass="";
        $this->db="crud1";

        $con = new mysqli('sql300.epizy.com', 'epiz_23534135', '1wrhZALfPLNG0e', 'epiz_23534135_crud1');
        $con->set_charset("utf8");


        /*$con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);

        if($con){
            mysqli_select_db($this->db, $con);
            echo "Conexion Exitosa";
        }else{
            echo "Error al conectar";
        }*/

    }

    public function consultaSimple($sql){
        mysqli_query($sql);
    }

    public function consultaRetorno($sql){
        $consulta = mysqli_query($sql);
        echo $consulta;
        return $consulta;
    }

}

?>
```

2. estudiantes.php

```html
<?php

//Clase de conexion incluida
include_once('conexion.php');

class Estudiante{

    private $id;
    private $cedula;
    private $nombre;
    private $apellido;
    private $telefono;
    private $edad;
    private $promedio;
    private $fecha;
    private $con;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->con = new Conexion;

    }

    public function set($atributo, $contenido){

        $this->$atributo = $contenido;
    }

    public function get($atributo){
       return $this->$atributo;
    }

    public function listar(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM estudiantes";
        $resultado = $this->con->consultaRetorno($sql);
        //$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        return;
    }

    public function crear(){

        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM estudiantes WHERE cedula =  '{$this->cedula}'";
        $resultado = $this->con->consultaRetorno($sql2);
        $array = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

        if($array > 0){
            return false;
        }else{      
            $sql = "INSERT INTO estudiantes (cedula, nombre, apellido, telefono, edad, promedio, fecha) VALUES (
                    '{$this->cedula}', '{$this->nombre}', '{$this->apellido}', '{$this->telefono}', '{$this->edad}',
                    '{$this->promedio}', NOW())";
            $this->con->consultaSimple($sql);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function eliminar(){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM estudiantes WHERE id = '{$this->id}'";
        $this->con->consultaSimple($sql);
    }

    public function ver(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM estudiantes WHERE id = '{$this->id}' LIMIT 1";
        $resultado = $this->con->consultaRetorno($sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

        //Set Interno
        $this->id         = $row['id'];
        $this->cedula     = $row['cedula'];
        $this->nombre     = $row['nombre'];
        $this->apellido   = $row['apellido'];
        $this->telefono   = $row['telefono'];
        $this->edad       = $row['edad'];
        $this->promedio   = $row['promedio'];
        $this->fecha      = $row['fecha'];


    }

    public function editar(){

        $sql = "UPDATE estudiantes SET (nombre = '{$this->nombre}', apellido = '{$this->apellido}', telefono = '{$this->telefono}', edad = '{$this->edad}',
                promedio = '{$this->promedio}' WHERE id = '{$this->id}')";
        $this->con->consultaSimple($sql);

    }

}

?>
```

```html
<?php
include_once('clases/estudiantes.php');

class ControladorEstudiantes{
    //Atributos
    private $estudiante;

    //Constructor
    public function __construct(){
        $this->estudiante = new Estudiante();
    }

    public function index(){
        $resultado = $this->estudiante->listar();
        return $resultado;
    }

    public function crear($cedula, $nombre, $apellido, $telefono, $edad, $nota1, $nota2, $nota3){

        $promedio = ($nota1 + $nota2 + $nota3) / 3;

        $this->estudiante->set("cedula", $cedula);
        $this->estudiante->set("nombre", $nombre);
        $this->estudiante->set("apellido", $apellido);
        $this->estudiante->set("telefono", $telefono);
        $this->estudiante->set("edad", $edad);
        $this->estudiante->set("promedio", $promedio);

        $this->estudiante->crear();

        return $resultado;
    }

    public function eliminar($id){

        $this->estudiante->set("id", $id);
        $this->estudiante->eliminar();

    }

    public function ver($id){

        $this->estudiante->set("id", $id);
        $this->estudiante->ver();

    }

    public function editar($id){
        $this->estudiante->set("id", $id);
        $this->estudiante->ver();
        $this->estudiante->editar();

    }


}

?>
```

4. inicio.php

```html
<?php

$controlador = new ControladorEstudiantes();
$resultado = $controlador->index();
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><b>Pagina de Inicio</b></h1>
    <table border ="1">
        <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Cedula</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th>Promedio</th>
            <th>Acción</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            while($row):?>
                <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
                    
                        </tr>";
                    <?php    
            endwhile;    
        
         ?>   
        </tbody>        
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En `conexion.php` tienes `mysqli_query($sql);`. Si usas *Estilo por procedimientos* el primer parámetro debe ser una conexión; pero como ya tienes una conexión mejor deberías usar el *Estilo orientado a objetos*.

Comment: Estoy usando poo

Comment: Para aclarar lo del *Estilo* puedes revisar la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php). `$con` se pierde y la necesitas para `mysqli_query`.